# Package dependencies in Android apk files

Tags: reverse-engineering, decompiling, android, android-applicationinfo

I am performing Android app reverse engineering (decompilation and further analysis). I wish to analyse the **package dependencies** between different packages inside the same apk file. Is there any tool which does this? Else, how can I deduce package dependency in apk files?

Comment: Are you looking for source code extraction from apk??

Comment: No, I have some understanding of how to recover src code using dex2jar/ jad etc. What I look for is "package level dependencies" that could be deduced from intermediate code (smali, jimple etc.) or from java code of android apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to analyse the package dependencies between different packages inside the same apk file. Please let me know if there is any tool which does this

A tool called Dexter is available to find out all the packages present in an apk. Also, if there is a program dependency among any 2 packages, Dexter show it with an edge. It could be noted that the edges do not have any weight to indicate the strength of the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The only dependencies that I have run into with apk files are with the framework from the device.  If you are dealing with a standard app available from the Play, then it generally contains everything that it needs inside its own package.

Some of the custom builds like Amazon Kindle Fire, Barns & Noble Nook, etc have built custom launchers and other services which then offer other functions through their frameworks.

The framework-res.apk is typically stored in the /system/framework location.  You can extract that from your device and place it in your apktool folder of your %userprofile%/~.  Apktool (I am assuming that is one of the tools you are using) will then reference it when it does the work.

Comment: I am looking to decouple an apk into packages like the pkg containing the source code for app, pkg for ad libs, pkgs for support libraries etc. If you have any idea how to identify the packages from reverse engineered smali code, please share.

Comment: Also, please read my realated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717248/how-to-find-all-the-packages-included-in-an-apk and the fist comment thread.